# Ng-Lightning ParseError 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: angular, ng-lightning

I am using ng-lightning components in my Angular 4 app. I am trying to build a bundle to deploy to a Tomcat server. I am getting the error below. Searching through Google it seems that ng-lightning may be ES6 and I need to babelify it to ES5. I attempted the following scripts in my package.json file but I still get the same error.

C:\myapp\node_modules\ng-lightning\ng-lightning.js:1
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
^
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

```
"clean": "rmdir /S /Q dist",
"newbuild": "npm run clean && tsc -p src/ --outDir dist",
"build_prod": "npm run newbuild && browserify -s main src/main.js > dist/bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] && npm run minify",
"minify": "uglifyjs dist/bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/bundle.min.js",
```

Do I need a different preset for ng-lightning? I am not using Webpack for this. I tried that but I got a different set of errors and I haven't fully learned how to use Webpack yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that ng-lightning is an es6 package and I needed to use "babelify" with an es2015 preset. I also needed to edit the script a little. One last item that I had to edit was the ng-lightning's package.json file. I needed to include a "browserify" transform in that file to allow it to be successfully bundled. This edit was the key piece that I was missing before.

**ng-lightning package.json:**

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] }]]
},
```

**app package.json "scripts":**

```
"clean": "rimraf dist",
"newbuild": "npm run clean && tsc -p src/",
"build_prod": "npm run newbuild && mkdir dist && browserify -s main -e src/main.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ] -o dist/app-bundle.js && npm run minify", 
"minify": "uglifyjs dist/app-bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/app-bundle.min.js"
```

**app package.json "devDependencies":**

```
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babelify": "^7.3.0",
"browserify": "^14.4.0",
"rimraf": "^2.6.1",
```